# How to obtain only the value of my variable using scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: optimization, python

when I minimize a function using scipy.optimize.minimize I get a big list of things as a result, but I would like to only get the value of my variable, this is my code
:

```
import scipy.optimize as so

def func_AC(r):
    return 1/((r**2)+1)

guess = 0

minimo = so.minimize(func_AC,guess)

print(minimo)
```

and this is what I get:

```
  fun: array([1.])
  hess_inv: array([[1]])
  jac: array([-1.49011612e-08])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
  nfev: 3
  nit: 0
  njev: 1
  status: 0
  success: True
    x: array([0.])
```

with only this values I would be really happy

```
success: True
    x: array([0.])
```

also I need my function to have bounds but I dont know how to, could anybody help me have the same code but with the bound r>=1? thanks in advanced

Comment: It is not clear what your question is. First, you mention that you do not like the result object returned by `scipy.optimize`. And then you mention that you want to modify an optimization problem that you have not explicitly described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, the values are stored in the members of the `minimo` object.  Explicitly

```
print(minimo.success)
print(minimo.x)
```

For the second part of the question as to how to setup bounds,

```
import scipy.optimize as so
from scipy.optimize import Bounds
import numpy as np

my_bounds = Bounds(0,np.inf)

def func_AC(r):
    return 1/((r[0]**2)+1)

guess = [2]

minimo = so.minimize(func_AC,guess,bounds = my_bounds)

print(minimo.success)
print(minimo.x)
```

The hidden trick here is that scipy optimize likes to have different variables expressed as elements of list.  That is the `r` is no longer a single variable, but rather a list of variables.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I was trying to accomplish!!